# Laravel: saving date to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, laravel-4

In my controller, when I `create` an event, it saves perfectly fine. The user enters a date in `dd-mm-yyyy` and it gets saved in MySQL `DATETIME` format. Then the `details` view renders it completely fine, just like the `edit` view via model binding.
As soon as I try to save from the `edit` form, the date somehow fails and returns `1970-01-01 00:00:00`.

I am not really sure why this only happens on my `update` method, as my `store` method is in essence the same.

```
$input = Input::all();
$input['plannedTime'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(Input::get('plannedTime')));
```

How comes the `update` method returns no error, validation is alright, but it still won't save it correctly?

Comment: What's the value of `Input::get('plannedTime')`?

Comment: The value of 'plannedTime' is a `string` of date format `d-m-Y H:i:s`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> The value of 'plannedTime' is a string of date format d-m-Y H:i:s.

There's your problem. PHP's `strtotime` does its best, but `04-05-2015 00:00:00` could be either April 5 or May 4, depending where you live.

As an example, on my install, `strtotime('04-13-2014 00:00:00')` fails (which'll get converted to 0, which'll get converted to 1970-01-01).

Laravel's `date` validation expects a value that strtotime can handle. If you're using an ambiguous date format, use `createFromFormat` to parse it, then `format` to spit it out in a more standard format.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i:s', Input::get('plannedTime'));
$usableDate = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Changed code to be as so:

`$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i:s', Input::get('plannedTime'));`

`$input['plannedTime'] = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Receiving now `Call to a member function format() on boolean` ($date in this case).

Comment: If `$date` is a boolean `Input::get('plannedTime')` was not `d-m-Y H:i:s`.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL never returns any error for invalid dates as far as i can remember, it just sets it to EPOCH and thats it!

You should enforce your dates to be always converted to a "Y-m-d H:i:s" format when communicating with your site and display the date in "d-m-Y" only on the output side.

You should try and use

```
public static DateTime DateTime::createFromFormat ( string $format , string $time [, DateTimeZone $timezone ] )
```

To create a datetime object from a format. If you know your format such as  in this case, then provide the format and get a date object back which will be persisted correctly!

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, Mathieu!
Now, when I am running the edited plannedTime through the validation in my model, I receive an error 'the planned time is not a valid date'.

My model describes 'plannedTime' as 'required|date'.